# How to input multiline words in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I've met a problem in using editbox.I want a mutiline inputDialoge in cocoss2d-x. is there a good solution?Any response is appreciated.

Comment: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/ios-multiline-edit-box/18349

Comment: can u please share you solution , that would be helpful to all